# How does fluorescent lamp produce audible sound when blinking?

Tags: discharge, fluorescent-lamp

A fluorescent lamp will often blink near end of its life. Each time it blinks it likely produces a clearly audible sound which is hard to describe but it's something in between a water dip falling onto water surface and a mouse chirping.

How does it produce the sound?

Comment: I don't think its the lamp, it probably is the ballast. I haven't seen this phenomenon on lamps with electronic ballasts.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The sound is somehow similar to vibrating glass so I'd guess it's the lamp itself. Perhaps you don't hear the sound with electronic ballast because the latter makes the lamp end its life differently. Do lamps blink with electronic ballasts?

Comment: Yes, although I think maybe not as often as in the old days. Maybe also not as "hard"?

Answer (score 4):

How does a lightning strike generate thunder?

The discharge into the gas pulses the atoms, while it also heats the gas. This all happens in a minute fraction of a second.

The single layer of glass can't do much to stop the vibrations this creates and as an effect you hear the glass vibrate along, giving the ticking the characteristic sound.

In flasher tubes inside big stroboscopes the tick is less flavoured, because the glass is thicker to relation, to keep from bursting at the high energy levels of the flashes.

If a starting pulse comes more as a wave, it can sometimes be that the tick is barely audible, because the last spark-over is of much lower energy. But in normal old-fashioned lamps the balast makes a sharp pulse creating a strong flash and as such a loud tick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the sound you hear is the sound of the *starter* trying to restart the discharge in the tube after it has ceased. Near their end of life fluorescent tubes cannot always maintain the glow discharge indefinitely, so they shut off and cool down. This makes the starter heat up and trip, trying repeatedly to restart the discharge in the almost exhausted tube. Each time the starter trips it makes a short, metallic, vibrating sound. Maybe that's the sound you hear.

This video explains [how a fluorescent lamp works](https://youtu.be/z55566ep0Hg) and may be relevant.

This other video shows explicitly [how a starter works](https://youtu.be/hhUGPu3DgHw) and you can hear the noise it makes when it trips.

And this is another video on [how a starter works](https://youtu.be/ig5e4RHfn0Q) (maybe with a bit better quality audio).

Comment: Its not so much that the tube can't maintain the glow discharge it is that the voltage across the tube rises to the point that the starter operates.  Normally with a good tune the voltage is below that of the starter.